# __block self reference cycle in ivar block in ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I've got some code with an apparent reference cycle in a block ivar. The following code causes a reference cycle and dealloc is never called:

```
__block MyViewController *blockSelf = self;

loggedInCallback = ^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
    if (success)
    {
        double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
        {
            [blockSelf.delegate loginDidFinish];
        });            
    }
};
```

However, if I create another `__block` variable to hold a reference to my delegate for the block's scope to capture, the reference cycle goes away:

```
__block id <MyViewControllerDelegate> blockDelegate = self.delegate;

loggedInCallback = ^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
    if (success)
    {
        double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
        {
            [blockDelegate loginDidFinish];
        });            
    }
};
```

Just want to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to assume your'e using ARC here. Prior to ARC, your first example would work just fine. With ARC the semantics of `__block` have changed. `__block` declarations are now strongly captured, rather than weakly. Replace `__block` with `__weak` in your first sample and all should work as expected.

As for what the second example works, you are creating a strong reference to the delegate, but  your that doesn't have a reference back to your object. Thus no cycle and everyone is happy.

I recommend reading Mike Ash's article on the changes introduced with ARC, especially around block capture and `__weak` http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I've updated my question's title to be more descriptive.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS 4.3, so I've had to use ``__unsafe_unretained`` instead, but it works, thanks!